# Catching panics in Golang

Tags: exception, error-handling, go

With the following code, if no file argument is given, a panic is thrown for line 9 `panic: runtime error: index out of range` as expected.

How can I 'catch' this panic and handle it when directly when passing something to it (`os.Args[1]`) that causes the panic? Much like try/catch in PHP or try/except in Python.

I've had a search here on StackOverflow but I've not found anything that answers this as such.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not open file")
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", file)
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Go is not python, you should properly check for args before you use it:

```
func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
         fmt.Printf("usage: %s [filename]\n", os.Args[0])
         os.Exit(1)
    }
    file, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", file)
}
```

Comment: Minor nit: you probably want either `log.Fatal(err)` (or possibly `os.Exit` after printing the message with `err` in it) in that final `if` block.

Comment: "Go is not python, you should properly check for args before you use it:" true but you probably want to do stuff like this within a test to check that your program is panicking as desired without throwing an error.  `recover` seems to be the way to accomplish a typical `try catch`

Comment: This is not a proper answer. In any language, you should check for possible errors and exceptions. The problem is that developers are human and make mistakes. The point of the question is to handle the panics when the developer has failed to handle the possible errors properly. The "too bad, you should have had thought about it" answer has never been helpful.

Comment: Go and Python both terminate the program with a stack trace for the error in question.

Answer (score 158):

A panicking program can [recover](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics) with the builtin `recover()` function:

> The `recover` function allows a program to manage behavior of a panicking goroutine. Suppose a function `G` defers a function `D` that calls `recover` and a panic occurs in a function on the same goroutine in which `G` is executing. When the running of deferred functions reaches `D`, the return value of `D`'s call to `recover` will be the value passed to the call of `panic`. If `D` returns normally, without starting a new `panic`, the panicking sequence stops. In that case, the state of functions called between `G` and the call to `panic` is discarded, and normal execution resumes. Any functions deferred by `G` before `D` are then run and `G`'s execution terminates by returning to its caller.
>
> The return value of `recover` is `nil` when the goroutine is not panicking or `recover` was not called directly by a deferred function. Conversely, if a goroutine is panicking and `recover` was called directly by a deferred function, the return value of `recover` is guaranteed not to be `nil`. To ensure this, calling `panic` with a `nil` interface value (or an untyped `nil`) causes a [run-time panic](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Run_time_panics).

Here is an example of how to use this:

```
// access buf[i] and return an error if that fails.
func PanicExample(buf []int, i int) (x int, err error) {
    defer func() {
        // recover from panic if one occurred. Set err to nil otherwise.
        if recover() != nil {
            err = errors.New("array index out of bounds")
        }
    }()

    x = buf[i]
}
```

Notice that more often than not, panicking is not the right solution. The Go paradigm is to check for errors explicitly. A program should only panic if the circumstances under which it panics do not happen during ordinary program executing. For instance, not being able to open a file is something that can happen and should not cause a panic while running out of memory is worth a panic. Nevertheless, this mechanism exists to be able to catch even these cases and perhaps shut down gracefully.

Comment: Please comment before downvoting. Why are you downvoting me for giving an answer for the literal question OP asked? OP specifically stated that he wants to recover from a panic. I wrote an answer how to do that. Whether it's the right thing to do is not mine to judge.

Comment: @OneOfOne index-out-of-bounds generates a panic as per spec. Totally works.

Comment: @Volker If he'd ask that, I would give him an honest answer. I might point out in an additional comment that this might not be the smartest thing to do. Who am I to judge the questions of others?

Comment: In this case, @OneOfOne answer was helpful to me preventing a potential bad habit. Your unopinionated post is appreciated though.

Comment: For future reference (since no one has mentioned it): inhaling jelly beans and/or mustard is a bad idea. Consider a different approach to whatever problem you are having.

Comment: Panic only when you know you can't continue, only crash. Crashing may mean quitting the whole program, returning an "internal error" message from an API or Web request, or ending some other high-level chunk of your program. Panics are slow, un-idiomatic, and easy to mess up use of (particularly when you have 80% err returns and 20% panics; you get the downsides of both), so don't use them for potentially recoverable situations like missing/duplicate object in database, network error, etc. Also, if writing a library, return err whenever the *caller* might be able to recover.

Comment: Or, imprecisely but intuitively: many programs have one handler catching the panics that are always possible (index out of range, nil pointer, out of memory, failed type assertion...), so that an unexpected error handling one request won't bring down the server. That should usually be the only such handler you need, and any `panic()`s you insert should be for problems that will always bubble up to that level.

Comment: defer must be a function call... can you please add '()' at the end of your defer statement. I cant edit it because i have to edit at least 6 characters^^

Comment: Came to this question to find out how to handle panics in go. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: `recover()` returns `interface{}`; this code will return a compile error: `cannot use recover() (type interface {}) as type error in assignment: interface {} does not implement error`

Comment: @mig Issue addressed.

Comment: This is a perfectly legit recommendation, and as far as I know the only way to be made aware of panic using services like airbrake for production servers (since a panic in a request processed by ServeHTTP won't stop the program).

Comment: Minor point, but you don't need parentheses in that if statement.

Comment: @DuncanJones Sorry.  It's a habit from programming in C a lot.

Answer (score 21):

Some Golang official packages use *panic/defer+recover* as *throw/catch*, but only when they need to unwind a large call stack. In *Golang's json package* using *panic/defer+recover* as *throw/catch* is the most elegant solution.

from http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover

> For a real-world example of panic and recover, see the *json package* from the Go standard library. It decodes JSON-encoded data with a set of recursive functions. When malformed JSON is encountered, ***the parser calls panic to unwind the stack to the top-level function call, which recovers from the panic*** and returns an appropriate error value (see the 'error' and 'unmarshal' methods of the decodeState type in decode.go).

Search for `d.error(`
at http://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go

In your example the "idiomatic" solution is to check the parameters before using them, as other solutions have pointed.

But, if you want/need to catch *anything* you can do:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    defer func() { //catch or finally
        if err := recover(); err != nil { //catch
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Exception: %v\n", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }()

    file, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not open file")
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s", file)
}
```

Answer (score 16):

First: You wouldn't want to do this. Try-catch-style error handling is no error handling. In Go you would check `len(os.Args)` first and access element 1 only if present.

For the rare cases you need to catch panics (and your case is **not** one of them!) use `defer` in combination with `recover`. See http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#recover

Comment: The cases are no so rare. E.g. see recommendations https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PanicAndRecover#usage-in-a-package

Answer (score 8):

We can manage panic without halting process using recover. By calling recover in any function using defer it will return the execution to calling function. Recover returns two values one is boolean and other one is interface to recover. Using type assertion we can get underlying error value 
You can also print underlying error using recover.

```
defer func() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        var ok bool
        err, ok = r.(error)
        if !ok {
            err = fmt.Errorf("pkg: %v", r)
        }
    }
}()
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to catch panics in a test case. I got redirected here.

> func.go

```
var errUnexpectedClose = errors.New("Unexpected Close")
func closeTransaction(a bool) {
    if a == true {
        panic(errUnexpectedClose)
    }
}
```

> func_test.go

```
func TestExpectedPanic() {
    got := panicValue(func() { closeTransaction(true) })
    a, ok := got.(error)
    if a != errUnexpectedClose || !ok {
        t.Error("Expected ", errUnexpectedClose.Error())
    }
}

func panicValue(fn func()) (recovered interface{}) {
    defer func() {
        recovered = recover()
    }()
    fn()
    return
}
```

Used from https://github.com/golang/go/commit/e4f1d9cf2e948eb0f0bb91d7c253ab61dfff3a59 (ref from VonC)

Answer (score 3):

Note that the recover treatment of a panic *Execution* error (such as attempting to index an array out of bounds trigger) might change with go 1.7 after [issue 14965](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14965)

See [CL 21214](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/21214/) and [its test](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/21214/6/src/runtime/crash_test.go):

> ### runtime: make execution error panic values implement the `Error` interface
>
> Make execution panics implement Error as mandated by [Run-time panics (specs)](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Run_time_panics), instead of panics with strings.

When you recover a panic error, you would be able to do:

```
if _, ok := recovered.(runtime.Error); !ok {
```

---

This is still being evaluated, and as [Dave Cheney](http://dave.cheney.net/about). mentions:

> I don't know what people are currently doing but from my POV this has been broken for a long time and nobody has complained so they are either explicitly relying on the broken behaviour, or nobody cares. Either way I think it's a good idea to avoid making this change.

Comment: The linked issue has been closed due to its age, not because implemented.

Comment: @kiamlaluno It was first closed in 2016, because implemented by https://golang.org/cl/21214 and https://github.com/golang/go/commit/e4f1d9cf2e948eb0f0bb91d7c253ab61dfff3a59. Then it was limited to collaborators, and finally, indeed, closed due to age. But it was implemented.

Comment: Oh, thank you. They didn't put any explicit, not created by bots, comment on the Github issue, and it seemed they didn't do anything to fix/change that. (The link to follow is indeed the one for _CL 21214_.)

Answer (score 1):

While `panic` in Go isn't idiomatic and shouldn't be used as exceptions in other programming languages, sometimes the need to *catch* them does arise.

In these cases I've found it useful to define a `CatchPanic` utility that translate `panic` into a checkable `error` to minimize divergence from Go's idioms.

For example:

```
func CatchPanic[T interface{}](f func() T) (ret T. err error) {
    defer func() {
        rec = recover()
        if rec != nil {
            err = errors.New(fmt.Sprint(rec))
        }
    }()
    return f(), nil
}
```

Usage example (oversimplified..):

```
func main() {
    arr := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    val, err := CatchPanic(func() int {
        return arr[5] // Will panic
    })
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

The return value of the lambda parameter can be adjusted to other use cases.

Do note that when possible it's advised not to relay on panic catching in Go and check before access is preferable.