# Golang error handling: understanding panic

Tags: go

I am quite new to Go and I am trying to grasp the `panic` function.

Up until now, I have been using this similar syntax to handle errors in programs:

```
func Find(i int) (item, error) {
  // some code

  if (not found) {
    return nil, errors.New('Not Found')
  }

  // if found:
  return myItem, nil

}
```

Then I stumbled upon the `panic` function. I am having a hard time understanding it. Is it possible to get rid of the `error` in the return statement and do something like this?

```
func Find(i int) item {
  // some code

  if (not found) {
    panic('Not found')
  }

  return myItem

}
```

If yes how do I handle the error when the function is called?

Many thanks

Comment: http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover. In this case, don't use it. It's only meant for exceptional "the world is on fire" circumstances.

Comment: Also of note: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#dont-panic

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025467/catching-panics-in-go-lang)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `recover` function.

```
func Find(i int) item {
    defer func() {
        if e := recover(); e != nil {
            // e is the interface{} typed-value we passed to panic()
            fmt.Println("Whoops: ", e) // Prints "Whoops: Not Found"
        }
    }()

    if (not found)
    {    panic("Not Found")
    }

    return myItem
 }
```

Refer: http://blog.denevell.org/golang-panic-recover.html